# Scipy's curve_fit not giving reasonable result

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting, curve

I have a simple `x,y` data set to fit, at least at first glance. The issue is that [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) gives back a *very* large value for one of the parameters fitted and I don't know if this is mathematically correct or if there's something wrong with how I'm fitting the data.

The figure below shows both the data points and the best fit obtained in blue. The curve used (`func` in the `MWE` below) has four parameters `a, b, c, d` being fitted:

- `a` gives approximately the `x` value where the curve attains it's half-maximum.
- `b` represents the `x` value where the curve *stabilizes*. This `func` value is given by the `d` parameter, ie: `func(b) = d`
- `c` is related to the maximum value of the curve at the origin: `func(0) = c*constant + d`
- `d` is where the curve stabilizes (black line in the figure).

The `b` parameter is the one I'm having issues with (see end of question), it's also the one I'm **most** interested in assigning a reasonable value.

[image]

The `MWE` shows the function being fitted and the results:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to be fitted.
def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return c * (1 / np.sqrt(1 + (np.asarray(x) / a) ** 2) -
        1 / np.sqrt(1 + (b / a) ** 2)) ** 2 + d

# Define x,y data.    
x_list = [12.5, 37.5, 62.5, 87.5, 112.5, 137.5, 162.5, 187.5, 212.5, 237.5,
    262.5, 287.5, 312.5, 337.5, 362.5, 387.5, 412.5, 437.5, 462.5, 487.5,
    512.5]
y_list = [0.008, 0.0048, 0.0032, 0.00327, 0.0023, 0.00212, 0.00187,
    0.00086, 0.00070, 0.00100, 0.00056, 0.00076, 0.00052, 0.00077, 0.00067,
    0.00048, 0.00078, 0.00067, 0.00069, 0.00061, 0.00047]

# Initial guess for the 4 parameters.
guess = (50., 200., 80. / 10000., 6. / 10000.)

# Fit curve to x,y data.
f_prof, f_err = curve_fit(func, x_list, y_list, guess)

# Values for the a,b,c,d fitted parameters.
print f_prof

# Errors (standard deviations) for the fitted parameters.
print np.sqrt(f_err[0][0]), np.sqrt(f_err[1][1]), np.sqrt(f_err[2][2]),\
    np.sqrt(f_err[3][3])

# Generate plot.
plt.scatter(x_list, y_list)
plt.plot(x_list, func(x_list, f_prof[0], f_prof[1], f_prof[2], f_prof[3]))
plt.hlines(y=f_prof[3], xmin=0., xmax=max(x_list))
plt.show()
```

The results I get are:

```
# a, b, c, d
 52.74, 2.52e+09, 7.46e-03, 5.69e-04

# errors
11.52, 1.53e+16, 0.0028, 0.00042
```

The `b` parameter has a huge value and also a huge error. By looking at the data plotted in the figure, one would estimate by eye that the value for `b` (ie: the `x` value where the data set *stabilizes*) should be around `x=300`. Why am I getting such a large value for `b` and its error?

Comment: I am afraid the problem is with the data you are fitting (or the function). First, you have a typo in the errors (should be f_err[1][1]). I have checked your example with a global solver and it gives me the same results in others parameters but I even get b = 3.56564242e+18. But there is no surprise, the derivative around point x = 300 is a real snail - it approaches minimum but very slow. You could check by hand - compute the partial derivatives by parameters with respect to the data and try to solve the system of 4 nonlinear equations.

Comment: @Martin thanks for pointing out the typo, I've fixed it (the value was fine though)

Comment: I know. I have checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is intentional or a mistake but it looks to me like 'b' will be correlated strongly with 'a' and 'd' and has no "interaction" with the independent variable 'x'.  If b/a is large enough, you could approximate 1/np.sqrt(1 + (b / a) ** 2)) ** 2  as a/b, so that your function becomes 
   c * function_of(x, a) - a/b + d

Your 'a' and 'x' values are large enough that this becomes very nearly  c*a/x - a/b + d.

As pointed by behzad.nouri, curve_fit can be slightly unstable compared to other minimizers, and always minimizes the least-squares.   But it does return the full covariance matrix  including correlations between variables (off-diagonal elements of your f_err). Use these!!

If you're sure 'b' has a value around 300, or are interested in easily switching between fmin and the levenberg-marquardt algorithm, you might find the lmfit package (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful.  It allows you to put bounds on parameters, easily switch between fitting algorithms, and also to do a more brute-force exploration of the confidence intervals for the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on `lmfit` Matt. Unfortunately I tried it applying all the minimizer methods shown here http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/fitting.html#fit-engines-label and the results are the same: the paramneter `b` is enormous. Even restraining it via a max value only results in that max value being returned, so it's of no use. Thank you again and +1 for the package recommendation!

Comment: what correlations do you see between variable a and b? If all the fitting methods are giving the same results and if constraining the value causes the limit to always be hit, doesn't that suggest to you that the problem is ill-posed?  Again, you essentially have c*a/x - a/b + d.    Unless 'a' and 'd' are known with very high accuracy, 'b' the uncertainty in 'b' is going to be very large.... that's what you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

you can use a penalty value for the norm of parameters, and use `fmin`:

```
from scipy.optimize import fmin

def func(x, a, b, c, d):
    return c * (1 / np.sqrt(1 + (x / a) ** 2) - 1 / np.sqrt(1 + (b / a) ** 2)) ** 2 + d

def errfn(params, xs, ys, lm, ord=1):
    '''
    lm: penalty maltiplier
    ord: order in norm calculation
    '''
    from numpy.linalg import norm
    a, b, c, d = params
    err = func(xs, a, b, c, d) - ys
    return norm(err) + lm * norm(params, ord)

params = fmin(errfn, guess, args=(xs, ys, 1e-6, 2))
```

above I am using a small penalty of `1e-6` and the fit result are

```
[6.257e+01   3.956e+02   9.926e-03   7.550e-04]
```

with a decent fit:

[image: fit]

**edit**: playing with the penalty function and the norm order, it gives a very good fit at

```
params = [  1.479e+01  -3.344e+00  -8.781e-03   8.347e-03]
```

[image: fit2]

Comment: Are you getting a negative value for the `b` parameter in the second line? That is definitely not ok, please read the definition/rationale of the `b` parameter on the question, it can never be negative. Your first line of values are very reasonable though, I'll give that a try.

Comment: The issue with this method is that by adjusting the _penalty_ I can make `b` return pretty much any value I want, which is not good.

Comment: @Gabriel that basically means your model is over-parametrized. that is there are too many ways to get a good fit to the data points, and there is no one true fit. consider reducing the number of parameters in the model.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look, it seems that a large `b` will eliminate the second term of `func()`:

When `b/a` goes to infinity, `1 / np.sqrt(1 + (b / a) ** 2)) ** 2` goes to zero.

This suggests to me that this part of the function is not needed in the model and is doing more damage than good.

Just set `func` to be:

```
c * (1 / np.sqrt(1 + (np.asarray(x) / a) ** 2) + d
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for me. The `b` parameter is the most important one in that function. +1 for the answer. Thank you!